# Eclipse does not show Tooltip

Tags: eclipse

I am Using Eclipse for android, I have installed SDK ADT bundle. While coding, some times I need to know description of Classes, Methods etc. When I hover my mouse over class, method definitions, it does not show the tooltip, after some time it begins to show it. This goes on and off. Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean the window that pops up when you move your mouse over classes and methods?

Comment: thanks @OjonugwaOchalifu...... it is not pops up window when i mouse over classes and method. And sometime it pop up but so late...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editors > Hovers

select `Combined Hover`.

You can restart Eclipse for good measure.